# Php/Mysql Multidemensional/Associative Arrays 2

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I've been on this code for almost a week and can't seem to get out of it.
I'm fetching rows from a database that looks like this:

id |    account    |    content        |    type        |    quantity
1         23494                 E                      38                  10
2          23494                   E                      13                   5
3          23494                   F                       38                  7
4          23494                   E                    6                    2

My Statement looks like this thus far:

```
// Make the query:
$qu = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE account='".$account."' ORDER BY timelog DESC $pages->limit"; 
$re = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $qu); // Run the query.

$roarr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($re, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $roarr[$row['account']][$row['content']][$row['type']] = $row['quantity'];

} // End of WHILE loop.
//print_r($roarr);

echo'
<tr>&nbsp;</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left"><b>Account</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>6Kg(E)</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>13Kg(E)</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>38Kg(E)</b></td>

    <td align="left"><b>6Kg(F)</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>13Kg(F)</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>38Kg(F)</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Date Created</b></td>
</tr>
';

$dataarr = array();
foreach($roarr as $account => $dataarr) {
    $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');

    echo '
      <tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
        <td align="left">'. $account .'</td>
     ';

    foreach($dataarr as $content => $data) {
         if($content == "E") {
              echo '<td align="left">', (isset($data['6']) ? $data['6'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
               echo '<td align="left">', (isset($data['13']) ? $data['13'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
               echo '<td align="left">', (isset($data['38']) ? $data['38'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
         } // Then I GET STUCK on the Else Part! HOW Do I display $content == "F" data on the right hand side?
    } //End Foreach
} //End Foreach
```

This is how I intend to display my results :

Account | 6KG(E) | 13KG(E) | 38KG(E) | 6KG(F) | 13KG(F) | 38KG(F) | Date

23494                        5               10             2                               7

, but I'm so stuck.

**Question:**
How can I arrange the results fetched in such a format?

**EDIT:**
I've Changed the database so as to focus more on the problem: Since the query fetches per account, there is only one account with rows shown as in the database above.

This is the array produced by $roarr:

Array ( [23494] => Array ( [F] => Array ( [6] => 2 [38] => 7 ) [E] => Array ( [38] => 10 [13] => 5 ) ) )

Thank You in Advance

Comment: You need to test with >= as you step through results. if there is a match for the column the print in that column, else print a blank column.  I would write it out for you but I think it is better practice to write it yourself.

Comment: There's an error in your array creation   $roarr[$row['account']][$row['content']][$row['type']] = $row['quantity']; check your opening and closing [ ]'s they're all over the place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like that instead of your internal foreach loop:

```
echo '<td align="left">', (isset($dataarr['E']['6']) ? $dataarr['E']['6'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">', (isset($dataarr['E']['13']) ? $dataarr['E']['13'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">', (isset($dataarr['E']['38']) ? $dataarr['E']['38'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">', (isset($dataarr['F']['6']) ? $dataarr['F']['6'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">', (isset($dataarr['F']['13']) ? $dataarr['F']['13'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">', (isset($dataarr['F']['38']) ? $dataarr['F']['38'] : '&nbsp;'), '</td>';
```

Comment: How many columns do you have?
You need only add extra `Date` column to the end of each row and close `<tr>` tag on the end of foreach step

Comment: Ok. I understand your problem. Your account could have both 'E' and 'F' values for content. Right?

Comment: It can't overshoot. You must add date `<td>` tag and close `<tr>` on every foreach step

Comment: I've updated the above question's database, coz your solution overshoots the "E" values and aligns correctly the "F" values. I'd like the alignment to happen no matter which order the values are fetched.

Comment: I understood your problem. Check my update on answer. It will help you

Comment: That's more like it @Michael. I wouldn't have thought along those lines for long time. Thank you for that answer